# Why publish .NET Core 2.1 Self-Contained Deployment with Configuration of Release is saved to Debug?

Tags: .net-core

I'm publishing my first .NET core app and I'm trying to do it with self-contained deployment so users can just use the app without installing anything else.

Everything is working ok but when I use this profile
[image]

I see the following output:

```
2>App -> C:\Users\ido.ran\Documents\dev\App\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64\ParametersEditor2.dll
2>App -> C:\Users\ido.ran\Documents\dev\App\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
2>App was published successfully to bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
```

Why is the deployment published to `bin\Debug` instead of `bin\Release`?

Comment: what's the default output of your `Release` configuration?

Comment: it will just publish to the folder that is selected as the Target path.

Comment: @Thangadurai you right :) I didn't notice this, can you write it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Publish Wizard will publish the files to the selected 'Target Location'.

[image]

If you would like to publish it to a different location, just change this location.